# What is the easiest way to setup human translations through a third-party service with Contentful?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I'm interested in setting up human translation workflows with Contentful through a third-party service like Smartling or Straker.  What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: This is a very broad question and might get closed as such, you'd have to narrow it down to a question about a more specific implementation if you want to recieve an answer that contains any substance. The only answer I can give you for this question is: "Create a UI extension: "https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/uiextensions/"

Comment: Smartling released Contentful connector
https://www.smartling.com/translation-software/translation-connectors/contentful-translation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything supported. You're going to want to get the content into XLIFF.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF

Write a process to *output* as XLIFF, and another process to update *from* XLIFF. But, understand that you're breaking new ground here.